# Grails 2.1: How to use "schema-export export"?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-2.0

I would like to (re)create my database schema using the command "schema-export". DDL generation works fine, but if I execute "schema export export", I get the following error, which suggest that there is something missing in a configuration file.

```
grails> dev schema-export export
| Compiling 1 source files.....
Exporting in environment 'development' for the default DataSource
| Error 2012-08-24 14:45:57,466 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - schema export unsuccessful
Message: No local DataSource found for configuration - 'dataSource' property must be set on LocalSessionFactoryBean
  Line | Method
->> 61 | doCall in SchemaExport$_run_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
| Error 2012-08-24 14:45:57,472 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - schema export unsuccessful
Message: No local DataSource found for configuration - 'dataSource' property must be set on LocalSessionFactoryBean
  Line | Method
->> 64 | doCall in SchemaExport$_run_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

My DataSource.groovy defines a "dataSource":

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}
...
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            username = "xxx"
            password = "yyy"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chrono_dev?autoreconnect=true"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Any suggestions how to fix this error?

Comment: Maybe I should add why I want to do this: I do not want grails to "create-drop" the schema on startup during development, because I don't want my test data to be deleted every time I restart the application. Also "update" does not always do the job right. I simply want to recreate the schema on demand, without restarting the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it works now, but it does. I have switched to Postgres, maybe it has got something to do with this.
Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is a bit different:

```
grails dev schema-export // no export
```

according to this:

http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html

If you are doing an import you may want to describe the datasource:

```
grails dev schema-export export --datasource=auditing
```

Also what is the name of your ddl you are trying to import?

Comment: I think the additional "export" is correct.
It sais: "grails [environment] schema-export [action] ['stdout'] [filename] [--datasource]". And "export" is a possible [action]. If I remove export, it just generates a DDL file, which is not what I want.

Comment: I don't know how to specify the datasource name, which is why I do not use the --datasrouce parameter. Is there a way to specify the datasource name? http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Plug-ins/dataSource.html has no details about it.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- Try defining your entire datasource in each environment block (rather than having that global shared one).   I've had troubles with this type of setup in `DataSource.groovy` before.
- Add a dialect line for MYSQL in your datasource definition. `dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`
- If none of that works, you could always just do this in a two step process.  Have `schema-export` dump things out to a file (no 'export' option), then paste its output into a SQL Editor and run.

Comment: Sadly that did not change anything. I will have to use a workaround, like the one that you suggested.